# Как в Postman подставить данные из recaptcha кода?

Tags: postman, recaptcha

Есть необходимость в постмане перед запросами авторизоваться.
Но для авторизации кроме логина и пароля нужен код recaptcha.
Как автоматизировать этот процесс, ато я что-то ни в гугле ни в ChatGPT не найду?

Спасибо большое.

Comment: Нужно прочесть **recaptcha** глазами и вписать что написано в запрос) в противном случае смысл **recaptcha** теряется.. это ведь Типа антибот)